# SQL database design for tags. How to handle missing relation between two tables?

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables in a PostgreSQL database (one for storing articles, one for all tags, and one for the relation between the two):

```
table: article
columns: article_id, title, content

table: tag
columns: tag_id, name

table: article2tag
columns: article_id, tag_id
```

For now I only have two tags in the `tag` table:

```
tag (table)
-----------
tag_id      name
1           apple
2           orange
```

I have an article (the one with ID 1) tagged with the two tags: apple and orange:

```
article2tag (table)
--------------------
article_id     tag_id
1              1
1              2
```

But let's say one of the tags in the `tag` table will be removed, for example the tag named `apple`, now `tag_id` in `article2tag` will point to an inexistent tag.

What is the proper way (if there is one) to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2):

That can be handled with foreign key constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE article2tag
            ADD FOREIGN KEY (article_id)
                            REFERENCES article
                                       (article_id);
ALTER TABLE article2tag
            ADD FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)
                            REFERENCES tag
                                       (tag_id);
```

That way, if you try to delete a tag that is still used in an article you'll get an error and cannot delete the tag.

You can also specify that, if a tag is deleted it will be removed from all articles with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

```
ALTER TABLE article2tag
            ADD FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)
                            REFERENCES tag
                                       (tag_id)
                            ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

You can also use that for the foreign key to `article`.

You probably don't know about primary keys too, so you might encounter an error when trying to create the foreign key constraints about the referenced column not being unique. In that case add primary key constraints to `article` and `tag`.

```
ALTER TABLE article
            ADD PRIMARY KEY (article_id);

ALTER TABLE tag
            ADD PRIMARY KEY (tag_id);
```

You should also define a primary key for `articel2tag` analogously.

```
ALTER TABLE article2tag
            ADD PRIMARY KEY (article_id,
                             tag_id);
```